# Limit range of trendline to the first couple of bars in clustered column chart

Tags: bar-chart, excel-charts, trendline

I'm trying to limit the *trendline* online to the first 2 bars of a clustered column chart.

The background being, say this is the 2nd week of January and I would like to show a trend between actual and forecasted hours. For the first two weeks of January where I have actual hours the *trendline* does a good job. However for the 2nd half of January, the *trendline* does not accurately reflect the trend as it only shows the forecasted hours not the actual hours.

In our business we forecast only the hardcore committed hours, typically 60% of the time dedicated to inflexible/predictable standard tasks. The rest, the actual hours are then added on top with variable, unforeseen tasks. Thus, I would like to make the *trendline* stop e.g. after the first 2 weeks, since I only have the actual hours/percentage of time spent for those 1st two weeks.

I have tried to achieve this by right clicking on the chart and clicking '<kbd>select data</kbd>' but that does not work.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  In this case it is difficult to see what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Its not completely clear what you're trying to do. But maybe your just missing a simple point here:

Instead of displaying *trendline* on the forcast serie, you may just need to display it on the actuals serie. Here is a visual of the difference you would have with *moving average*:

[image]
... Remember, if it solves your issue, kindly approve this answer. You didn't do it for [Zolvas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34980676/6019417) which obviously solved your problem. It will also give points to you too.